# Incorrect syntax Error in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement search facility on my form. Procedure accepts search content as search parameter

```
--[dbo].[sps_selectemployeedetails] 1,10,'aaa' alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sps_selectemployeedetails] @page INT,@size INT,@search varchar(max)=null  AS BEGIN
    declare @totalrow int
    DECLARE @offset INT
    DECLARE @newsize INT
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        IF(@page=0)
      BEGIN
        SET @offset = @page
        SET @newsize = @size
       END
       IF(@page=1)
      BEGIN
        SET @offset = @page
        SET @newsize = @size-1
       END
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
        SET @page = @page - 1
        SET @offset = @page*@size 

        SET @newsize = @size-1
      END
    SET NOCOUNT ON  if(@search is null)      begin   SET @sql = '
     WITH OrderedSet AS
    (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS ''Index''
      FROM tbl_employeeDetails  
    )    SELECT * FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @offset) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), (@offset + @newsize))      end     else    begin   SET @sql = '
     WITH OrderedSet AS
    (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS ''Index''
      from tbl_employeeDetails e,tbl_EmpAdddress a where e.FirstName LIKE ''%''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @search) + '''%''  and a.EmpID=e.EmpID
    )    SELECT * FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @offset) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), (@offset + @newsize))  end
        EXECUTE (@sql)    END
```

And i got an error saying incorrect syntax near 'aaa'

Comment: If you add `PRINT (@SQL)` before your `EXECUTE` you'll see your dynamic SQL, and very quickly (most likely) see the problem.

Comment: Also, why is `@search` a `varchar(MAX)`, when you convert it to a `varchar(12)` in the query? This is also open to injection, although limited due said `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of extra single quotes around your search criteria.

```
SET @sql = '
    WITH OrderedSet AS
    (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS ''Index''
      from tbl_employeeDetails e,tbl_EmpAdddress a where e.FirstName LIKE ''%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @search) + '%''  and a.EmpID=e.EmpID
    )    
    SELECT * FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @offset) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), (@offset + @newsize))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sp_executesql` and pass in parameters.  The code looks something like this:

```
@sql = '
WITH OrderedSet AS (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS ''Index''
      FROM tbl_employeeDetails  
     )
SELECT *
FROM OrderedSet
WHERE [Index] BETWEEN @offset AND (@offset + @newsize)
';
sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@offset int, @newsize int',
                   @offset=@ofset, @newsize=@newsize
```